# Asignar valor almacenado a un TextView

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Estoy empezando a practicar con los NavigationDrawer, estos se crearon de manera automática y estoy intentando asignarle a un TextView un valor guardado en una preferencia. El problema está en que no se como llamar a ese TextView desde el MainActivity. Este es xml donde está el TextView:

```
nav_header_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="75dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/file"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNombrePreferenciaGuardado" //este es el textview al que quiero asignarle el nombre
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Prueba"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Este es el diseño de la actividad principal:

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Y el app_bar:

```
app_bar_main.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Barberia.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Barberia.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_agregar_turno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_turnos_clientes" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Esta es mi ActivityPrincipal:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NombreBarberiaPreferencia nombreBarberiaPreferencia;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        nombreBarberiaPreferencia = new NombreBarberiaPreferencia(this);
        if(nombreBarberiaPreferencia.traerValorGuardado() == null
                || nombreBarberiaPreferencia.traerValorGuardado().isEmpty()
                || nombreBarberiaPreferencia.traerValorGuardado() == ""){
            alerta_Nombre_Tabla();
        }else{
            String nombre_barberia = nombreBarberiaPreferencia.traerValorGuardado();
        }

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fabAgregarTurno.setOnClickListener(view ->
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show());
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    private void alerta_Nombre_Tabla(){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        AlertDialog anuncio = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_nombre_base_de_datos, null);
        final EditText nombre_bd = view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_bd);
        final Button guardar_cerrar = view.findViewById(R.id.guardar_cerrar);
        try {
            guardar_cerrar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if(nombre_bd.getText().toString() == ""
                        || nombre_bd.equals("")
                        || nombre_bd.getText().toString() == null
                        || TextUtils.isEmpty(nombre_bd.getText())){
                    nombre_bd.setError("Debe ingresar un nombre válido.");
                    nombre_bd.requestFocus();
                }else{
                    nombreBarberiaPreferencia.guardarValor(nombre_bd.getText().toString());
                    anuncio.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception exception){
            Log.d("NOMBREBD", "alerta_Nombre_Tabla: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
        anuncio.setView(view);
        anuncio.show();
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo asignar el nombre almacenado en la preferencia a ese `TextView` que quiero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `TextView` en realidad se encuentra dentro del `NavigationDrawer` por lo tanto debes hacer referencia a esta vista para obtener sus elementos.

Obten la referencia del NavigationView y de su "header":

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

al obtener la referencia del header dentro del `NavigationView` busca el `TextView`:

```
TextView navUsername = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombrePreferenciaGuardado);
navUsername.setText("Escribe el texto aquí");
```

Comment: Buenísimo, muchas gracias por la explicación

Answer (score 1):

Solución que hallé:

```
        final TextView nombre = binding.navView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.tvNombrePreferenciaGuardado);
        nombre.setText("Barberia " + nombre_barberia);
```